# What are the best ways to safely delete data in databases with great performance?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I want the best ways to preserve the data deleted by users to add the feature to retrieve the deleted data from the database with the best performance when querying, especially when there is a huge amount of data.

I came up with two methods:

- adding a column with a boolean value whose value is true, meaning the row has not been erased and false otherwise
- add a copy of each table that carries the deleted data from each table

If you have other good methods, please let me know or comment on the above two methods which perform better especially when there is big amount of data.

With my greetings and thanks in advance to everyone who read my problem or tried to help me, thank you.

Note: I am using Entity Framework

Comment: One solution is **Temporal** in your *RDBMS*. Temporal is a database feature that was introduced in ANSI SQL 2011. [Temporal tables in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 1):

The first method you mention is basically a soft-delete, but it should work the other way round.  e.g.  True = row is deleted.

While an update such as this may often be "quicker" than a delete operation on the DB, it may depend on the DB you are using and the way in which your data is structured.

The problem with soft deletion is that every single one of your select queries will need updating (to filter the deleted rows) and that will affect the performance of each of them (this may be minor and barely noticeable, but requires code/SQL changes).

Typically, a soft-delete is also seen as a temporary solution, and a hard delete is then usually executed later.

This is because a DB will be more efficient and need less resources when it has less data in it, and when each table has fewer rows (there are of course ways to support tables with billions of rows, but that makes the DB more complex to operate.  And some DBs which are designed better to handle this than others.)

The second method can be achieved by using triggers which execute "OnDelete".
But again, triggers can be bad for performance and will slow down your delete command (again this may or may not be noticeable depending on the amount of data).
The advantages of this, are that your main table remains small and efficient, you don't need to change any of your queries, in fact it is totally agnostic for the client.  The disadvantage is that you need to manage this in the DB as Entity Framework cannot handle this.

So which way is best for you?

Well, you need to determine this yourself based on your business requirements.  If performance is critical, then do some tests on a large dataset and see which suits.

There is nothing wrong with using both methods on different tables in the DB.